# Rotate line in Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, line

I have a line in a canvas that I would like to rotate en x number of degrees,while maintaining the start point at the middle of the canvs, I was wondering what the formula to figure out the end point coordinates is?, something like

```
degrees=xnumberofdegrees
lineEndPoint=degrees*someformulaforxandy
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, bg="white")
canvas.pack()
rotatedline=space.create_line(250,250,lineEndPoint)
```

the start point should always be 250,250 since the canvas's size is 500x500, so I would only need the end point. Any help is welcome.

Comment: I am quite disappointed with this question - why is it not about how to rotate an existing line in the `Canvas`? It is possible to move existing objects ("ovals" etc.), but what if we want to change the endpoints arbitrarily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straightforward application of trigonometry.

```
angle_in_radians = angle_in_degrees * math.pi / 180
line_length = 100
center_x = 250
center_y = 250
end_x = center_x + line_length * math.cos(angle_in_radians)
end_y = center_y + line_length * math.sin(angle_in_radians)
```